# matrices from square with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, matrix

everyone,

I have some problem here. So, I have to create matrices, for example 5x5, and every index should appear in html like squares. I created span template for the box after that created script for matrices and gave this span to every index to multiply it, but it doesn't work poperly. This is what appears to me

```
enter code here
[object HTMLSpanElement][object HTMLSpanElement][object HTMLSpanElement][object HTMLSpanElement][object HTMLSpanElement]
[object HTMLSpanElement][object HTMLSpanElement][object HTMLSpanElement][object HTMLSpanElement][object HTMLSpanElement]
[object HTMLSpanElement][object HTMLSpanElement][object HTMLSpanElement][object HTMLSpanElement][object HTMLSpanElement]
[object HTMLSpanElement][object HTMLSpanElement][object HTMLSpanElement][object HTMLSpanElement][object HTMLSpanElement]
[object HTMLSpanElement][object HTMLSpanElement][object HTMLSpanElement][object HTMLSpanElement][object HTMLSpanElement]
```

Here is my code

```
    enter code here
    <style>
        html {
            background-color: #E6E6FF;
        }
        #square{
            width: 30px;
            height: 30px;
            background: #000;
            display: inline-block;
            border: 1px solid #fff;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
<div id="matrixBox">
    <span id="square"></span>
</div>

    <script>

    var x = 5;
    var y = 5;
    var matrix = [];
    var content= '';
    var matrixBox = document.getElementById("matrixBox");
    var square = document.getElementById("square");

    for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        matrix[i] = [];
        for (var s = 0; s < y; s++) {
            matrix[i][s] = square;
            content += matrix[i][s];
            document.getElementById("matrixBox").innerHTML = content;
        };
        content += "<br>";
    };
    </script>
</body>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Look the code below. Now the "Matrix" is the array where as u can use this for your calculation

```html
<html>
  <style>
        html {
            background-color: #E6E6FF;
        }
        #square{
            width: 30px;
            height: 30px;
            background: #000;
            display: inline-block;
            border: 1px solid #fff;
   color:#fff;
   text-align: center;
   vertical-align: abs-middle;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
        }
    </style>
 
</head>
<body>
<div id="matrixBox">
   
</div>

   
</body>
<script language="javascript">

    var x = 5;
    var y = 5;
    var str='';
 var matrix=new Array();
 

    for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
   matrix[i]=new Array();
        for (var s = 0; s < y; s++) {
   matrix[i][s]=i;
            str+=" <span id=square> "+ i + " </span>  ";
         };
        str += "<br>";
    };
 
  document.getElementById("matrixBox").innerHTML = str;
  alert(matrix);
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for that. But I really want to know how to give "square" styles to every indext. I want this metrics to appear something like one of the sides of rubik's cube. But with same colors.
http://www.syedgakbar.com/app/blog/cube-face.png

Comment: woooooooow! thank you so much! I smash my brain to think two days.
:)